# Using Guid as Id column in NHibernate causes format exception when using MySQL

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, guid

When I define the NHibernate entity/mapping to use Guid as identity column I receive an exception. The Guid column is generated as a varchar(40), but the content seem to be binary.

Is there a solution to this? For now I'm just using plain ol' int, but it would be nice to know for future projects! :)

Comment: What is the exception? Did you create the column as varchar(40) or did NHibernate generate the schema?

Comment: NHibernate generated it. I don't have the exception available right now, but it was an exception concerning the format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySql Connector documentation states that from version 5.2 of .NET connector they treat GUID's as **BINARY(16)** not **VARCHAR(40)**.

> Since current MySQL dialect in nhibernate doesn't updated to reflect this change *(actually  [an issue](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1838) is prepared)* 
>   you need to manually convert these
>   fields to BINARY(16) after nhibernate
>   generate the schema.

Comment: I have been getting the same thing in the last few days.  this is a real life saver.

Answer (score 5):

Another update to this is that the latest connectors use Char(36)

This option was introduced in Connector/NET 6.1.1. The backend representation of a GUID type was changed from BINARY(16) to CHAR(36). This was done to allow developers to use the server function UUID() to populate a GUID table - UUID() generates a 36-character string. Developers of older applications can add 'Old Guids=true' to the connection string in order to use a GUID of data type BINARY(16).