# NHibernate (Hibernate) Auto Increment On Property

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, hibernate, nhibernate

Using nHibernate (or Hibernate as the mapping does not differ), I want to create an object with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `EntityId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
    `Number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`EntityId`),
    Key(`Number`)
);
```

Ive tried using generated properties, additional id tags, specifying the sqltype in column tags under the property tags, and messing with defaults, insert, update, and not null attributes but nothing seems to work. Am I just not able to map this in Hibernate mapping syntax? How can I get a property that is not the primary key to auto increment?

I would post the mappings Ive got but none of them work.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
Using this mapping which I think is a good starting point but not quite what I want:

```
<class name="TheEntity" table="table">

  <id name="Id" 
     column="EntityId"
     generator="guid.comb" />

  <property name="Number" 
            generated="insert"
            insert="false" update="false" />
</class>
```

The schema in the database is generated as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `EntityId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EntityId`)
);
```

which is not the desired behavior. Nor does nHibernate, through some means, insert a sequence into Number. Generated Properties, as shown above, from what Ive read rely on the database taking care of the insertion and updating entirely through something like a trigger. I do not want to use a trigger to do something as basic as auto_increment however since there is a built in facility already for this.

Any ideas?

Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use notation like this to generate id for postgres:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "financialAnalyst_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "financialAnalyst_seq_gen", sequenceName = "financialAnalyst_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
```

Comment: Just a caveat to your answer, if your sequence doesn't exist in the database, you either need to create it using an SQL script, or set hibernate to create-drop mode so that Hibernate will create the sequence for you.

Comment: Wont the Id annotation make that the Primary Key? I need the Primary Key to be EntityId but a secondary key and the auto_increment to be Number

Comment: I copied to many lines. I think it would generate sequence without using id

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure where is the problem, but the mapping could be like this:

```
<class name="TheEntity" table="table">

  <id name="Id" 
     column="EntityId"
     generator="guid.comb" />

  <property name="Number" 
            generated="insert"
            insert="false" update="false" />
</class>
```

The Number:

The generated value, which is not representing **id** could be marked as [5.5. Generated Properties](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-generated). A cite:

> `generated="insert"` - states that the given property value is generated on insert, but is not regenerated on subsequent updates.

We are also helping NHibernate with explicit declaration to NOT insert and upate.

The Guid - EntityId:

I am not using MySQL, so not sure if there is still some issue with guid mapping - check
[Using Guid as Id column in NHibernate causes format exception when using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034879/)

But in general, it could be like this, when NHibernate uses generator for us, to create new EntityId values. If the application creates the EntityId different value, just use `generator="assigned"`

The entity class in C# then should look like:

```
public class TheEntity 
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ive confirmed there is no issue with Guids or generating Guids. I am able to use nHibernate to generate those fine. But, using the mapping you have there, my table has no auto_increment value when nhibernate generates the schema in the database. All inserts to the table have null in the Number field which would be expected since we are saying do not insert this field and do not update it but the Number field is not marked as auto_increment either. I need nHibernate to generate a Guid (which it does) and for it to mark Number with auto_increment on schema creation.